# Add OS X Native Fonts to X11

Tags: macos, fonts, x11, xterm

I am starting to use xterm for my default terminal.  My only issue, is that I don't like any of the fonts.  Is it possible to install more fonts for use in X11.  I'd really like to get Monaco.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming modern Linux,

- put .ttf file in ~/.fonts
- xterm -fa Monaco

It's possible the font doesn't end up called exactly Monaco, just open a font selector in any program to see what Linux ends up calling the font and then use that name. If there's a space in the name you'd have to add quotes,

xterm -fa 'My Font Name'